# Tracking Asset History

Tags: platform-event, asset

Currently receiving asset enrichment calls to a Platform Event so that I can update my assets.

General Flow:
[image]
I need to have a separate store of an asset whenever a certain field is updated from the source data into the platform event.
An asset is the same product, although the product's type can change through it's lifecycle in the source system.
Whenever this type changes, this needs to be tracked, and reported.

I can't use field-tracking as I need to pull this into reporting and compare all fields for the asset.
**Possible solutions:** snapshot reporting, or a separate object which creates a record.
**The preferred solution in my org:** create a new asset, and inactivate the last one

What is the best way to achieve this both performance wise and reporting wise?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.